# Create Dynamic Controls Using DataBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an object that i am PASSING to my user control as a property. Then loop through the object properties and create controls at runtime in different tabs based on their order day. 
Please go through the attached image for better understanding.

Its working fine, but this is so WINFORM type, is it somehow possible to create controls at runtime using WPF binding, dependency property or anything like that.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is it somehow possible to create controls at runtime using WPF binding

Yes, it is possible. This is what data templates are intended for. The basic rule is: don't create *controls*, create *data* and display the template, which defines how that data should be represented:

```
public class ComponentViewModel : ViewModel /* ViewModel is a basic implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface */
{
    public ComponentViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
        {
            new ItemViewModel { IsActive = true, DateTime = DateTime.Now, Name = "Lemons" },
            new ItemViewModel { IsActive = true, DateTime = DateTime.Now, Name = "Melons" },
            new ItemViewModel { IsActive = true, DateTime = DateTime.Now, Name = "Apples" },
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set
        {
            if (isActive != value)
            {
                isActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool isActive;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private string name;

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return dateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (dateTime != value)
            {
                dateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DateTime");
            }
        }
    }
    private DateTime dateTime;
}
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ComponentViewModel();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<!-- Binding defines data source -->
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- The template defines data representation -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Window>
```